# Active MQ consumer is receiving only the alternative messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

Requirement : One activemq queue should run in one machine (say machine1) .That queue should be accessed from the machine1 and another machine(say machine2).And the listener will run only in machine1.So, all the messages that i send to machine1 and machine2 should enter into the queue avaialble in the machine1 and should be received by the listener avaiable in the same machine(machine1).

problem : All the messages that i have send to machine1 and machine2 are entering in to the queue but the listener is receiving only the alternative messages.Say if 1, 3 , 5 and it is not able to receive message 2 ,4 .....

Observation: Suppose if have listeners in machine1 and machine2 it is receiving properly i.e; listenr in machine1 receives 1, 3, 5..... and the listener in machine2 receives 2,4,6...........

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ is using RoundRobin distribution by default. So if as you explained, you have 2 consumers on your queue (machine1 and machine2), machine1 will receive only half of the messages.
Even if you have no process handling messages on machine2 the ActiveMQ client on this host is probably consuming them.
If you want that the 2 clients can consume the messages you have to use a Topic instead of a queue.

Comment: we need to persist the data and process any server issue. If we use the topic, How to persist data?. Also we have to read the msg in order. So only one consumer(reciver) has to be run.

Comment: @SelvamR Use a durable subscriber if you want to persist and save messages for topics where subscribers are offline: http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html